# Inheriting abstract classes - choosing pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have abstract class which is:

```
public abstract class Ingredient 
{
    private string name;
    private decimal price;

    public Ingredient(string name, decimal price)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.name;
        }
    }

    protected decimal Price
    {
        get
        {
            return this.price;
        }
    }

    protected void ChangePrice(decimal newPrice)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The price changed from {0} to {1} for engridient {2}", this.price, newPrice,this.name));
        this.price = newPrice;
    }


}
```

And then I have Lots of ingredients which inherit Ingredient:

```
Tomato:Ingredient {//implementation}
Cheese:Ingredient {//implementation}
Mushrooms:Ingredient {//implementation}
Onion:Ingredient {//implementation}
```

But I want my ingredients to have some type of measurement which can be `decimal Quantity` or `int Count` based on type of the ingredient. For example Tomato is countable(3 tomatoes) and cheese is measured by `decimal Quantity` (30 g of cheese). I tried to make abstract classes:

```
public abstract class Countable
{
   protected abstract int Count { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Qantable
{
    protected abstract decimal Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

but classes can not have two base classes.(I can not have `Tomato:Ingredient, Countable {//implementation}`) I can`t use interfaces because I want my measurements to be visible only for the child elements and I want to encapsulate the measurements (so when I want to change some base logic in Countable for example I don't have to change every child implementation)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To achieve this your `Countable` and `Qantable` have to derive from `Ingredient`.

```
public abstract class Countable : Ingredient 
{
   protected abstract int Count { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Qantable : Ingredient 
{
    protected abstract decimal Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

So the classes which derive from `Countable` or `Qantable` will be `Ingredient`, too.